# PostgreSQL CASE statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, case, plpgsql

This is from the official documentation (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html)

> and two forms of CASE:
>
> `CASE ... WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END CASE`
>
> `CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END CASE`

This doesn't work:

```
select case when 1 < 2 then 'a' else 'b' end case from pg_database limit 1;
```

It works with `end` instead of `end case`, though:

```
select case when 1 < 2 then 'a' else 'b' end from pg_database limit 1;
```

This is with PostgreSQL 9.4.6.

Why doesn't the syntax in the official docs match the syntax that the server apparently requires?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing documentation for [**PL/pgSQL**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS) with the one for [**SQL**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE). You link to the manual for PL/pgSQL, but your code displays an SQL expression.

Both use the key word `CASE`, but it's not the same thing. `CASE` in PL/pgSQL is a *control structure* for the procedural language, while `CASE` in SQL is a conditional *expression*.

You are not the first to be confused. There are other minor differences in the syntax. For instance, PL/pgSQL allows a *list* of values for the ["simple `CASE`" variant](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#AEN62721), which is not possible in SQL:

```
... WHEN expression [, expression [ ... ]] THEN
```

Would be nice to have in SQL as well, but the standard doesn't allow it and Postgres sticks to the standard.

Comment: Modern SQL allows list of expression in SQL `CASE` too. The procedural `CASE` is based on modern standard, SQL `CASE` is still ANSI SQL 99 compliant (missing optional feature F263). The reason, why SQL `CASE` missing this feature is simple - no body wrote it for Postgres.

Comment: @PavelStehule: Oh, interesting, this might be low hanging froot for an ambitious developer.